# Bipartite Graph or not

Tags: algorithm, bipartite

[image]

I wonder if this graph a bipartite or not. As I found B-C-J is an odd-length cycle however when I draw the BFS no edge join the samen layer. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's exactly what you said, BCJ makes a cycle so it cannot be a bipartite graph.

There are another cycles, like EGABC.

You cannot have odd-length cycles in bipartite graphs, because it would mean that 2 vertices in the same side would be connected to each other.